# Can't get loaded model attributes in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I hava a model, transaction-result, where I have loaded all of the associations in my afterModel hook prior to hitting this point. You can see on the `transactionResult` console output that it's `runResult` association is loaded.

[image]

I'm able to clearly access the data I want via `_data`

[image]

But when I try to `get` the `runResult` association, I receive what appears to be an empty Ember object.

Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Can you build a minimal test case that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem in any other instance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure this is the source of your problem but when you get the result of an association ember often return a promise, can you try something like that

```
model.get("runResult").then(function(runResult){
 console.log(runResult)
})
```

Comment: I reworked my route's model and after model to load my model's differently and eventually found a solution that worked.